# Upload File with CURL into Website

Tags: batch-file, curl, post, cmd

I try to Upload a File into a Website with cURL on Windows CMD. The html-code looks like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Filebrowser?Path=/S71500/" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkUploadFile()">
<td><input id="filebrowser_upload_filename" type="file" name="filename" size="30" maxlength="80" style="background-color: transparent;"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Datei laden"></td> 
</form>
```

The command i am using is:

```
curl -F "filename=@/Users/Me/FILE.so" http://localhost:8080
```

The fail-message is:

```
Warning: setting file FILE.so failed!
curl: (26) read function returned funny value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes it works for me when I remove " or ' when posting format args on Command Prompt.

But I guess it depends on the code on your server side, whether it will deal with those symbol or not.

Answer (score 5):

for me, it was a permissions thing. Curl wasn't able to read my file because it wasn't readable. try:

```
sudo chmod a+r /path/to/your/file
```

also, make sure to verify that you are logged in as either root or the owner of the file

```
ls -l /path/to/your/file
```

will give you info about permissions, ownership, and group for example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 792139 Jul  2 11:23 file.txt
```

file.txt is readable by root, "me" and members of the group "users" - writable only by root, and not executable by anyone. it contains 792139 bytes

Comment: Essentially the same issue for me: had a mistake in the filename in the curl command, which resulted in not being able to read the file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same error, while trying to upload with curl:

```
Warning: setting file testimage.png’  failed!
```

It comes out to be because my curl command line contained spurious invisible characters from a copy/paste from browser. I copied the command line into a text editor like Sublime Text and then back into terminal: suddenly everything worked.

Probably some UTF8 / ASCII issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-F`, we have to use `--form-string`. Then it will work.

Answer (score -3):

You should place a PHP code in the root directory of your server as below

upload.php

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

keep in mind that you must use the argument a capital F (for Form). Lowercase f is for fail

Comment: upload.php you may require if you are using apache2/lighttpd etc on server side. If you are using flask and others - the issue may be somewhere else. My case, UTF8 / ASCII issue - typed and worked

Comment: curl complains that it has an issue reading the file. This answer tries to remedy the server. IMO completely unrelated.